# Decode application/octet-stream

Tags: android, c, windows, delphi, web

I have an issue with data coming from the internet. I have a package coming from the internet that has the content-type:application/octet-stream.

My question is how do i decode it to readable values (such as 1,4.321,-2.6013 etc)? or is there any application that can do this?

For example:

3ecccccd is 0.400 (http://gregstoll.dyndns.org/~gregstoll/floattohex/) some are real numbers. 07d0 is 2.000

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you want to provide further information relevant to your question, please [edit] it. Take care to edit the *question* and not an *answer*. (Editing answers is allowed, but it should be to improve the answer, not to clarify the question.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTTP's `Content-Encoding` header only applies to how data is encoded inside of the HTTP message itself, not how the data itself is encoded outside of HTTP.  There is no `Content-Encoding` header present in your example, so HTTP is not encoding the data in any way, it is giving you the raw data as-is.

When HTTP's `Content-Type` header is `application/octet-stream`, that mean the data (after decoding it based on the `Content-Encoding`, if any) is raw 8bit data, the sender does not know what the actual type of the data is.  Without a more meaningful `Content-Type` to tell you what the data actually represents, the only thing you can do is analyze the raw data and make educated guesses about what it might be, unless you know through other means what the data is supposed to be.

Usually, binary data formats have a header/signature at the front of the data to identify what the data is, so you might start with that.

Until you can identify the data type, you cannot know which bytes represent what kind of values, what endian is used for multi-byte values, etc.  In short, you need more information about the data you are downloading in order to know how to process it.

Comment: i understand. you are right. after doing some brute force, i know that some values are 1,2 and 4 bits long. however, identifying data-type, is kinda ... hard, i might say.

Comment: `String guessedType = URLConnection.guessContentTypeFromName(url);` Could maybe work too

Answer (score 4):

That content type does not indicate any *encoding*. All it means is that the data represents a stream of (8-bit) bytes. How they're encoded is an entirely separate matter. To discover the encoding, you can look at other headers (such as Content-Encoding), or else the encoding might be implicit, in which case you'll need to consult documentation. Then choose an appropriate decoding strategy based on that.

Comment: so i stated "decode it to readable values", so transforming the raw data to human readable values, as i wrote between brackets. if you would have read the post, it says"content-type:application/octet-stream". so i pretty much know what you asked, but the values come in forms from 1-4 bits long :( this is where i get stuck. thank you.

Comment: The thing you asked how to do was *decode*. The only information you have about your data is the *type*. (If I hadn't read your post, I wouldn't have known that, so please don't make false accusations about me.) My answer is that the *type* isn't what determines how to decode. You need different information, and once you have that, it's what will drive your next action.

Comment: no, no, no. first, i'm not accusing. i'm here for help, not for doing stupid stuff. then, i said "decode it to readable values", not plain decoding. either way and anyway, do you have any idea for a starting point? now, i'm using a hex editor and manually doing things. a post with a picture of what i'm trying to do, do you think it will help? thanks

Comment: Read what is written to you... You can't DECODE it to readable values without knowing which ENCODING was used. All you have is what TYPE the data is - not how it was ENCODED. You need to look at the Content-Encoding header (if there is one - if not, you need to ask the sender of the data how to decode it). You do not have enough information from the Content-Type in order to determine how to decode it...

Comment: ok ... don't be all mad at me. maybe i'm not that great. i've posted the picture of the packet and with a sample below it. maybe now i'm more clearer in what i wanna do. thanks.

Comment: No picture to be seen anywhere - and it won't help anyway. Unless you know the method used to ENCODE, you can't DECODE. It's really that simple. So you need to find out how the data is ENCODED before you can DECODE it.

Comment: You don't have enough information to DECODE it. You don't know the ENCODING format. You say that 3ECCCCCD is 0.4 (assuming IEEE Single Precision flotaing point) - I say that it is 1053609165 in Little-Endian 32-bit integer format. Or 3452750910 in Big-Endian 32-bit integer format. So you see - without knowing the ENCODING format, you really can't DECODE it, as all these values are perfectly valid DECODINGS of the 4 bytes you mention. You need to know the ENCODING used in order to DECODE it - plain and simple...